# k8s / namespaces - Create "child" namespace

Tags: kubernetes, overlay

**Would it be possible to share pods between namespaces in Kubernetes?**

---

Given a setup like the following:

| pod | namespace |
| --- | --- |
| A | team_1 |
| B | team_1 |
| C | team_1 |
| D | team_1 |

This is what I'd like to achieve:

| pod | namespace |
| --- | --- |
| A | team_1 |
| B | team_1 |
| C | team_1 |
| D | team_1 |
| A | team_1_JIRA-12 |

I'd like to create (on the fly) a new namespace,
specific to a given pull request, that only "overrides" a handful of pods,
while still being able to communicate with pods from parent ns.

Comment: Why not use Labels & Selectors? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/

Comment: would u mind elaborating a bit? How would I be able to deploy `A` without affecting the `A` of the given ns?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes doesn't allow you to have a pod shared between 2 namespaces. However, you can define a service for the pod A called service A and access the service A in the other namespace `team_1_JIRA-12` using kubernetes DNS. You can use cURL to access pod A in `team_1` namespace using its service as follows:

```
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx
kubectl exec -it nginx-6799fc88d8-cx84f -- bash    
root@nginx-6799fc88d8-cx84f:/# curl http://A.team_1
```

Comment: You cannot access pods this way. While this can be true in case of services, it is not when it comes to DNS resolution of pods. Take a look at [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods) section in kubernetes docs. Maybe you meant a `Service` that exposes such `Pod` but your answer may suggest that you can access a `Pod` by its `<name>.<namespace>`.

Comment: Updated answer to explain better

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to share pods between namespaces in Kubernetes?

**Short answer:** No, it is not possible.

As [Malathi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237402/malathi) already mentioned in her answer, a `Pod` cannot belong to more than one namespace.

Take a look at [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) as they seem to be the right solution for your use case. As you can read in docs:

> If you want to control traffic flow at the IP address or port level
> (OSI layer 3 or 4), then you might consider using Kubernetes
> NetworkPolicies for particular applications in your cluster.
> NetworkPolicies are an application-centric construct which allow you
> to specify how a pod is allowed to communicate with various network
> "entities" (we use the word "entity" here to avoid overloading the
> more common terms such as "endpoints" and "services", which have
> specific Kubernetes connotations) over the network.
>
> The entities that a Pod can communicate with are identified through a
> combination of the following 3 identifiers:
>
> Other pods that are allowed (exception: a pod cannot block access to
> itself) Namespaces that are allowed IP blocks (exception: traffic to
> and from the node where a Pod is running is always allowed, regardless
> of the IP address of the Pod or the node) When defining a pod- or
> namespace- based NetworkPolicy, you use a selector to specify what
> traffic is allowed to and from the Pod(s) that match the selector.